# How to combine several imported files into a list to one dataframe in R within a function?

Tags: r

I have several .csv files that I import into a list and for now do some processing on each file separately using the code below and export then results for each of the files separately. What I would like to do is after doing the processing on each of the files separately to combine them into one dataframe. I know my code is not reproducible but I think it is enough to get an answer:

```
#Import all files in a list
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)


#Because the script process all the files at the same time but separately I name the output files witha suffix 1-19 indicating the species
#Order of files 1-19
i = 1:length(myfiles)

fn <- function(i) {
  data = myfiles[[i]]

#Separate data for tries that are alive and actually dead
  dataDead <- subset(data, YValues==1)
  dataAlive <- subset(data, YValues==0)
  
  
  #Average probabilities for alive and dead trees across countries
  meanDead <- aggregate(dataDead$MortPredicted, list(dataDead$Country), FUN=mean)
  meanDead <- meanDead %>% rename(meanDead = x,
                                  country = Group.1)
  
  meanAlive <- aggregate(dataAlive$MortPredicted, list(dataAlive$Country), FUN=mean) 
  meanAlive <- meanAlive %>% rename(meanAlive = x,
                                    country = Group.1)
  
  means <- merge(meanDead, meanAlive, by = "country", all = TRUE)

write.csv(means,"means.csv")
}

#Run function 
lapply(i, fn)
```

Within the function I process individual files from `myfiles` but in the end I want to combine them into one dataframe. What would be the best way?

Comment: If you `mylist` is a list of data.frames with the same columns, you can  do `do.call(rbind, mylist)` to combine them.

Comment: @Roland it is a list of columns. Would I use that within the function or before? Because I want to keep the processing of the files separately. I will edit the post to illustrate that a bit further...

Comment: Let you function return `means` and do `do.call(rbind, lapply(i, fn))`? If you want to have only one output file, pass the combined data.frames to `write.csv`. An alternative approach would utilize the `append` argument of `write.table`.

Comment: Please don't do that (`Reduce(rbind, L)` @I_O, iterative binding is horribly inefficient and will slow to a crawl with more data. Just do as Roland suggested and use `do.call(rvind, L)`. For similar results but some more control, you can use `dplyr::bind_rows(L)` or `data.table::rbindlist(L)`.

Comment: Sorry; I'll remove my comment (just to notify so yours won't be orphaned)